# Integrated Amp Configuration

Tags: audio, sound-system

I have a Peachtree Audio DAC, and a sonos Connect Amp. I went with the Peachtree Audio to have the benefits of the 'warmer' effects on my digital media. And I went with the Sono Connect Amp to be able to connect to my NAS or stream directly.

**My question is what is the best configuration for my amps (if any)? Or is there another hardware item I can buy to make the puzzle pieces fit?**

Before I got the Connect Amp, I had played my digital media over USB connected to my DAC. But now with the Connect, if I have a network cable running from my NAS to the Sonos Connect Amp, will my DAC ever get a chance to play its part? I'm guessing no? I'm a little confused.

My complete system is:

- DAC: Peachtree Audio Nova
- AMP: Sonos Connect Amp
- Speakers: Bose 901 (don't ask why haha)
- SW: Sunfire SDS 12